# Python - Change the sheet index in excel workbook

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to move an Excel sheet say of index 5 to the position of index 0. Right now I have a working solution that copies the entire sheet and writes it into a new sheet created at the index 0, and then deletes the original sheet.

I was wondering if there is another method that could push a sheet of any index to the start of the workbook without all the need of copy, create and write.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the function from XLRD module can help you

where you can get the sheet contents by index like this:

worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(5)

and then you can copy that into some other sheet of a different index, like this:

workbook.sheet_by_index(0) = worksheet